# The Recored script contains no steps in loadrunner. This is the error when i stop the recording in loadrunner it will not Generate Script

Tags: loadrunner

[![This is the error when I stop the recording in load runner. So I anyone know how to solve the problem][1]][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sbe7a.png

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible reasons for this:

- You are recording the wrong protocol
- Your application is self contained and does not communicate to a server
- Your traffic filtering excludes all communication
- You are not running as an administrative level user on your desktop

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this but turning on the setting to use the LoadRunner proxy for capturing traffic when recording.

**Turning on LoadRunner proxy:**

1. Open Virtual User Generator
2. Select menu *Record* and open *Recording Options*
3. Go to *HTTP Properties*
4. Make sure the option `☑ Use the LoadRunner Proxy to record a local application` is turned on

You can also turn on the proxy manually via Windows (LoadRunner does this for you if you turn on the setting above). Micro Focus documentation says:

> Specify the port on which the LoadRunner proxy will listen, by default, port 8888.